# Unknown column in 'field entry'

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am tring to a insertion into a mysql table via PDO. when I run the code, I get the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'testing' in 'field list' when using testing as the first input for the first row in the Html code below.
`

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Test)  VALUES ($first, $Test)";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

```html
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="page_ac.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Test </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="71">Name</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="301"><input name="name" type="text" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="Test" type="text" id="Test"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have not quoted your values, so it thinks you're referencing a column, not a string constant. Also, your code is very susceptible to injection attacks, you should read up on prepared statements and bound parameters, rather than just executing queries directly.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. This is the first script i have written in php. I will look into injection attacks. All the help is apprieciated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not escaping the values properly.  I would use PDO's method to prepare the values of your insert and then execute the query with the values as an array. The following code will escape the input values as strings in PDO.

```
// replace your variables with question marks
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Test)  VALUES (?,?)";
// prepare the sql to execute and get passed back a resource
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// pass the parameters as you would of in the query, in the array
// first variable matches first question mark and so forth
$stmt->execute(array($first,$Test));
```

It is always recomended you escape and sanitize your user input before using it inside a query otherwise you are allowing a possible SQL injection to happen. PDO's [prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method helps with that.